# Problem on persistence Unit and Oracle NLS

Tags: java, oracle, eclipselink, ora-12705

I have this persistence unit:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
 <persistence-unit name="HIAEWebservice">
 <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
 <class>alsc.ws.persistence.InCareAdmission</class>
 <class>alsc.ws.persistence.InCareCancelSchedule</class>
 <class>alsc.ws.persistence.InCareSchedule</class>
  <properties>
   <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
   <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.163.67:1521:EMRPPROD" />
   <!-- I work in this example without user / password.-->
   <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.user" value="interface_hiae" />
   <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.password" value="interpprod" />
  </properties>
 </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I get this error when I try to insert on Oracle database:

```
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1 
ORA-12705: Cannot access NLS data files or invalid environment specified
```

In my server I don´t have Oracle client.. I think it's the problem but is there any solution that I don't need to use Oracle client ?

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, your server doesn't need the Oracle client on it to run using the thin client driver.

However, the Oracle driver appears to be looking for NLS data files.  `classes12.jar` (for Java 1.2-1.3), `ojdbc14.jar` (for Java 1.4), `ojdbc5.jar` (for Java 5) or `ojdbc6.jar` (for Java 6) may or may not have them depending on the version.

For the ones that have them as a separate download on Oracle's [JDBC driver download page](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/java/sqlj_jdbc/), have them named `nls_charset11.jar`, `nls_charset12.jar`, or `orai18n.jar` depending on the Oracle version and Java version.